# how to achieve python task using local bq operator from airflow

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, bq

while working on project came across one situation where we want to perform few task using airflow but we are not allowed to use python operator but instructed to use local BigQuery operators. can anyone help me with such code like to setup airflow variable or how to write conditional code which will get executed by BQ operators. is it possible ?
if not then my next que is like is it possible that fetch result from BQ table using BQ operator and assign it to one python variable so want to use both BQ and python operator, is there any way for this?

Comment: which action you want to perform using bq operation ? please provide some example of input, task and output. Also try to show what you have today and what you have tried, please.

Comment: no...ex. i want to set airflow variable by fetching value from BQ table.

Comment: You can perform the operations in bigquery without the python operator. [Here is an code example](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_bigquery_queries.html) of how to create datasets, tables and query it only using the Bigqueryoperator. Please confirm if that is what you are looking for, than I can post a more detailed final answer.

Comment: i am executing one select query using BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator operator now i want to use this return result (which is always one row) in another python operator. so can we do xcom_pull from the query executed by BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is a sample of how to use a BigQuery operator and sending data to another task using cross communication`xcom_pull`.

You can use the `BigQueryGetDataOperator` or `BigQueryOperator` to query the data with custom queries. Those operators will return a list for you, so you can get it in another task. I've use it in a bash operator in the example:

```py
from airflow import models
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import (
    BigQueryGetDataOperator,
)
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT_ID", "<project-name>")
BQ_LOCATION = "europe-north1"
TABLE_NAME="<table-name>"
DATASET_NAME = os.environ.get("GCP_BIGQUERY_DATASET_NAME", "<ds-name>")


with models.DAG(
    "example_bigquery_operations",
    schedule_interval='@once',  # Override to match your needs
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    tags=["example"],
) as dag:

    get_data = BigQueryGetDataOperator(
        task_id="get_data",
        dataset_id=DATASET_NAME,
        table_id=TABLE_NAME,
        max_results=1,
        selected_fields="name",
        #location=BQ_LOCATION,
    )

    
    get_dataset_result = BashOperator(
        task_id="get_dataset_result",
        bash_command="echo \"{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('get_data') }}\"",
    )
    
    get_data >> get_dataset_result
```

```
[2021-12-06 17:12:07,641] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: example_bigquery_operations.get_dataset_result 2021-12-05T00:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host airflow-worker-c92mz
[2021-12-06 17:12:07,937] {taskinstance.py:1254} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=example_bigquery_operations
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=get_dataset_result
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2021-12-05T00:00:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2021-12-05T00:00:00+00:00
[2021-12-06 17:12:07,939] {subprocess.py:52} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2021-12-06 17:12:07,939] {subprocess.py:63} INFO - Running command: ['bash', '-c', 'echo "[[\'Tom\']]"']
[2021-12-06 17:12:08,242] {subprocess.py:74} INFO - Output:
[2021-12-06 17:12:08,245] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - [['Tom']]
[2021-12-06 17:12:08,246] {subprocess.py:82} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
```